# flutter firebase use two or more attributes with .equalto

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to use two attributes with .equalto()?

For example:

```
final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
databaseReference
    .child('team')
    .orderByChild(_userId) 
    .equalTo("participant" || "admin") // something like that
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no SQL `OR` clause in the Realtime Database. So you cannot filter the teams to be either a "participant" or an "admin".

There is however a solution that might work but only if those "values" are in a range. In your case, you can get all teams matching "admin" or an "participant" using:

```
final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
databaseReference
    .child('team')
    .orderByChild(_userId)
    .startAt('admin')
    .endAt('participant');
```

The problem with this approach is that it will also return teams of other types that are between "admin" or "participant", such as "non-participant" if it exists. If you only have two values, then it will work perfectly fine.

If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), then you can find there [Query#whereIn(String field, List<? extends Object> values)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#whereIn(java.lang.String,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.lang.Object%3E)) method that can help you solve this issue without any problem.